# Hibernate: Query entities which contain a specified element in a CollectionOfElements?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, collections

Let's say I have this entity (for Hibernate):

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @CollectionOfElements
    @IndexColumn("phones_index")
    Set<String> phones;
}
```

For example, I want to get instances of Person where their phones contain "555-1234".
How can I do a query on this? I am looking for something similar to:

```
session.createCriteria(Person.class)./*something*/.add(Restrictions./*something*/"555-1234").list();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi you can try this one

```
String phone = "555-1234";
Person person= (Person) session.createQuery("from Person p join p.phones pl where pl = :phone").setString("phone", phone).uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want Hibernate's `Restrictions.in()` method, which takes a property name as the first argument, and either an array or Collection of objects as the second.

See also: [The Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#in%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

**Edit:** Upon re-reading your question, I think you can use any of the relevant `Restrictions` methods, in particular, `eq`:

```
session.createCriteria(Person.class).add(Restrictions.eq("phones", "555-1234")).list();
```

Comment: @Willi: Doesn't work for me, the accepted answer does though.
Also there is an open issue in the hibernate bugtracking system concerning this: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-869

Comment: Doesnt work, plz see http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-869